# Is it considered bad practice to split a single form among multiple partial views?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am currently working on an ASP.NET MVC 3 app where I have a particular view that is setup like a wizard (using a jQuery plugin). Each of the wizard steps is part of a single form, where each "step" is split in to its own `<div>` element. I decided to create partial views for the contents of each "step". I did this for a few reasons. One being that it keeps the code for each step neat and organized. The other being that it allows me to more easily/neatly include or exclude steps from the wizard on the server side.

Right now, my "main" view looks something like the following:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm)
{
    <div class="step" id="step1">
        @Html.Partial("Step1")
    </div>

    <div class="step" id="step2">
        @Html.Partial("Step2")
    </div>
}
```

I am wondering if doing something like this would be considered bad practice and if I should just consolidate the code for all "steps" in to a single view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, nothing inherently wrong with that approach.

There's a small performance overhead, but likely to be of no consequence.

If it makes it easier for you to develop and maintain, feel free.

Edit: If you're worried about mapping sub-models, as we referred to in the comments, consider using ViewData.ModelMetadata.PropertyName in the partial view to derive the ID's of the input controls.

Comment: Thanks Steve. The one issue I have been going back and forth on with this is how to handle the view model. I typically like to have one view model per view/partial view. If I created the view models for each of the partial views and then passed them as parameters to `Html.Partial` couldn't I potentially run in to issues with binding when the form is posted back to the server/controller?

Comment: This approach could be helpful in some cases too. If your partial Step2 was designed in a way it could be re-used.  For example, maybe Step2 could be used on a Create/Insert page and also on a page that serves as an Update/Edit function.

Comment: As long as the ids of the input fields are relative to the parent model, you won't. But if you're not going to re-use the partial views with other models, there's no real need to pass anything other than the main model.

Comment: As of right now, my parent view model has a property with the view model type for each of the partials. So something like `Step1ViewModel Step1ViewModel {get; set;}`. Each of my partials is then using the parent view model as the model object, and they define their form fields like `@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Step1ViewModel.SomeStep1Value)`.

Comment: @Matt: The partials could be reused as they are written now. However, there are just a few things that I don't like, which caused me to ask the initial question. One is that in order to use them properly, they would have to be rendered inside of a form tag. The other is that the partials are currently using the parent view model object, so that I can properly use the Html helper methods to generate form fields and do not have to hard code DOM IDs or create custom model binders